# Change order of months scale_x_date ggplot

Tags: python, python-2.7, ggplot2, python-ggplot

I am plotting a time series of ground snow coverage as a function of timestamp using the `scale_x_date()` option in python's `ggplot` package (I assume this question applies equally for `ggplot2` in `r`, but specifying just to be clear). The default order of months on the x-axis is, of course, January through December going left to right.

However, for my application (where data spans the winter months) it would be preferable to change the order of the months so that a "year" starts and ends in the summer. For instance, the x-axis starts in July and ends the following June.  Is this possible?